# PHP stream_socket_client vs. cURL in TCP SSL

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I have a problem using `cURL` to POST XML to a TCP address with SSL. I have to pass an SSL certificate in the request which contains the private key + certficate to verify myself.

I just ran a test with a library using `stream_socket_client()` and it uses the `stream_context_set_option` to add an option `local_cert` in which it passes the certificate. Now I can get myself verified using this method, but I cannot do it in cURL. All I get is a `connection reset by peer` error which means the certificate verification failed. What's the difference? Do I have to abandon cURL because it would be (in my opinion) a much cleaner solution.

`$content` is valid XML.

```
    $headers = [
        "Content-type: text/xml",
        "Content-length: " . strlen($content),
        "Connection: close",
    ];

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'epptest.ficora.fi');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PORT, 700);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, __DIR__ . '/certificate.pem');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE, 'PEM');

    $output = curl_exec($curl);

    echo 'Error ' . curl_errno($curl) . ': "' . curl_error($curl) .'"';

    var_dump($output);
```

cURL verbose:

```
 * Rebuilt URL to: epptest.ficora.fi/
* Hostname in DNS cache was stale, zapped
*   Trying 87.239.122.59...
* Connected to epptest.ficora.fi (87.239.122.59) port 700 (#0)
> POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: epptest.ficora.fi:700
Accept: */*
Content-type: text/xml
Content-length: 406
Connection: close

* upload completely sent off: 406 out of 406 bytes
* Recv failure: Connection was reset
* Closing connection 0
```

Comment: From the documentation of CURLOPT_SSLCERT: *When using a client certificate, you most likely also need to provide a private key with CURLOPT_SSLKEY.*

Comment: I actually tried that, with two separate files. Doesn't work.

Comment: A "connection reset" is a strange error for this because you get it if the server has closed the connection even though the client tries to write on it. Usually you get a handshake failure on SSL problems instead. But maybe you get a connection reset after the SSL handshake was done because the server does not like the HTTP request itself.  A packet capture might be useful to better see what's really going on.

Comment: You mean cURL verbose?

Comment: I meant packet capture (wireshark, tcpdump) but maybe cURL verbose will also help.

Comment: I can try that although a weird solution proposal..

Comment: No need for a packet capture now. The reason is clear now. Wait for answer.

Comment: If you mean the 'not fine transferred..' i actually updated the response with a more current verbose. The earlier came using the wrong certficicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'epptest.ficora.fi');
> ```

You URL does not contain a method like `http://` or `https://`. In this case cURL assumes `http://` only and tries to connect directly to the server, i.e. without a SSL handshake. This can be clearly seen from the verbose cURL output. To fix this use a correct URL, i.e. use the correct method at the start of the URL.

Comment: Oh, man, that was it! I now got a response: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Comment: @Rcls: at least you are trying the SSL handshake now :). But still strange because you've set CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to 0 (which is a bad idea, better set a proper CA path).

Comment: Yeah well their documentation is complete garbage. Nowhere do they state that it's https plus I forgot you need that prefix for cURL to undestand it's SSL. I set the VERIFYTYPEER to 0 because i'm running it on localhost without SSL. I'll change it to true when I upload it to my server that has SSL.

Comment: Now I just have a major problem with the connection being timed out. Takes over three minutes with nothing but with stream_socket_client() it actually takes ~5-10 seconds.

Comment: @Rcls: I recommend to ask a separate question about this and also show the code you have for both implementations there and the answer of the server.